# I'm having problems with how to print multiple outputs from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im new to programming and was set a task where I had to ask the user for there name and a number. I had to print the name where each individual letter is printed on a separate line. The second part is that I had to ask the user to enter a number and that it would repeat the same output by the number given by the user

My code:

```
name = input("Please enter your name:")
num = input("Please enter a number:")
for index,letter in enumerate(name,1):
    for num in range(0,9):
    print(letter)
```

My desired result was this:

```
Please enter your name: Taki
Please enter a number: 3
T
a
k
i
T
a
k
i
T
a
k
i
```

the result was this:

```
Please enter your name: Taki
Please enter a number:3
T
T
T
T
T
T
T
T
T
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
k
k
k
k
k
k
k
k
k
i
i
i 
i
i
i
i
i
i
```

Plz help

Answer (score 1):

A brute force approach is

```
name = input('Enter a name: ')
num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
for i in range(num):
    for j in name:
        print(j)
```

Here, `name` is a string which is iterated over each character in the j-loop.

In your code, the `num` loop from 0 to 9 is wrong. You need to print for `num` times, not 9 times (0-9). So the range has to be `i in range(num)`. This is why each character was being printed 9 times in your output.

Also, remember to type cast `num` variable to `int` while taking the input as Python treats all inputs as string by default.

Answer (score 0):

You have your loops in the wrong order. And your range should be to `num` not `9`

```
name = input("Please enter your name:")
num = input("Please enter a number:")
for i in range(num):
    for letter in name:
        print(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input("Please enter your name:")
num = input("Please enter a number:")
result = [char for char in name] * int(num)
print('\n'.join(result))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get it done, using itertools:

```
import itertools 

count = 0
name = input("Please enter your name:")
num = int(input("Please enter a number:"))
for i in itertools.cycle(name): 
if count > num * len(name)-1: 
    break
else: 
    print(i, end = "\n") 
    count += 1
```